# generate_id in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm having problems printing the HTML tags out while generating an ID. I've created two for loops to generate ids for each `<small>` but I can't figure out how to generate the HTML properly. Specifically I cannot print out the second paragraph in the paragraph
paragraph bold block. Any help appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="right.xsl"?>

<div>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#d1e11">(5:30 - 7:30 p.m. Downtown)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d1e17">(6:00 - 8:00 p.m. Burnaby)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#d1e23">(5:30 - 6:30 p.m. Downtown)</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h3>Info Sessions</h3>
  <a name="d1e11"></a>
  <p>Full-time Programs (CST, CIT Diplomas and BTech)</p>
  <p>March 8, 2012 </p>
  <b><small>(5:30 - 7:30 p.m. Downtown)</small></b>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a name="d1e17"></a>
  <p>Computing Part-time Studies</p>
  <p>March 28, 2012</p>
  <b><small>(6:00 - 8:00 p.m. Burnaby)</small></b>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a name="d1e23"></a>
  <p>HTP - Technical Web Designer (TWD)</p>
  <p>March 21, 2012</p>
  <b><small>(5:30 - 6:30 p.m. Downtown)</small></b>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</div>
```

XSLT file

```
<xsl:for-each select="div/b">
  <li>
    <a href="#{generate-id(small)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="small"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>

</ul>
</div>
<h3>Info Sessions</h3>

<xsl:for-each select="div/b">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>   
  <p><xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::p"/></p>  
  <a name="{generate-id(small)}"><xsl:value-of select="small"/></a>
  <hr/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: can you maybe reformat the question? I tried to take a stab at it but there are missing pieces that I would not want to guess. Please post a well formed XML input and then separately post your XSLT (ideally a full fragment). Then indicate what part of your source document you have issues with. The easiest way would be to post the result you're getting along with the result you would rather expect

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::p"/>
```

In XSLT 1.0, xsl:value-of outputs the value of the first node in a node-set (in document order) and ignores the others. (I therefore guess that you are using XSLT 1.0). Your expression selects all the preceding siblings, and outputs the first of them. You want to output only the immediately preceding sibling, which is

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::p[1]"/>
```

Comment: I had no idea that reverse axes were numbered in reverse document order. Thank you.